# Create An IF Statement If GROUP_CONCAT doesn't return any results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a GROUP_CONCAT:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN c.twitter IS NOT NULL AND 
c.twitter <> '' THEN CONCAT('!',c.twitter) END SEPARATOR ' ') AS tweetWinners
```

This works great when the user has a twitter name in the database.  I then store this like so:

```
 $tweeters = $row['tweetWinners'];
```

Which gives me a list like:

```
@twitteruser1 @twitteruser2 @twitteruser3
```

However, I want to display two different options:

```
if ($tweeters == '') {

echo "Something";    

} else {

echo "$tweeters";    

}
```

But it always jumps to the else even if there aren't any twitter users.

Any help would be appreciated so that I know

Comment: Check with `if ( trim( $tweeters ) == '' ) {`

Comment: This doesn't do anything unfortunately which is strange.

Comment: Anybody got any other ideas? Using `if ( trim( $tweeters ) == '' ) {` now skips the $tweeters and goes on to the else.

Comment: What is displayed after `echo "$tweeters";`?

Comment: And also run the sql statement prepared either using phpmyadmin or console and see if it returns any rows?

Comment: `echo $tweeters` returns nothing as it should do.  But I've tried what you've said and `== NULL` but still it is ignoring the first part of the IF

Comment: To check NULL values you've got to use the `IS NULL` operator (or `IS NOT NULL`), see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null and [working with NULL values] (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/working-with-null.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` returns `NULL` if there are no non-NULL-Values.
see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

`NULL` is not an empty string. `COALESCE` might help.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce